# MySQL multidimensional query trouble

Tags: mysql

I have the table venta, this table has this structure:

```
id  can tot fec         hor            cod_f     per_f tdt des com   cdv    cliente     fdc     local
1   1   39  07/08/2014  11:36:28 a.m.   2112    GUSTAVO V   0       00003   Gustavo 07/08/2014  xtorr
2   1   59  07/08/2014  11:37:31 a.m.   2222    GUSTAVO V   0       00005           07/08/2014  xtorr
3   2   398 07/08/2014  11:37:35 a.m.   2233    GUSTAVO V   0       00005           07/08/2014  xtorr
4   2   358 07/08/2014  11:38:30 a.m.   3333    GUSTAVO V   0       00007           07/08/2014  xtorr
5   1   259 07/08/2014  11:38:34 a.m.   3113    GUSTAVO V   0       00007           07/08/2014  xtorr
```

cod_f is the code for the item in the inventory, can is the number of pieces sold of that item for that sale, and tdt is the type of the transaction. I have 5 types of transaction: E, S, V, D, and T .

I want to do a multidimensional query where I have the next result. The column should count how many E, S, V, D, and T types of transactions were made for that code on that day.

```
cod   E S V D T
2112  0 0 1 0 0
2222  0 0 1 0 0
2233  0 0 2 0 0
3113  0 0 1 0 0
3333  0 0 2 0 0
```

This query must be for 1 specific day and for one specific store;
fdc is the cut date and local is where it was sold. Then I suppose it must have

```
where fdc = '07/08/2014' and local = 'xtorr'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why the 2 in the V col for 2233 and 3113? That doesn't correlate with your sample data. I would expect 1 for every row in the V column. Btw you would better use DATE and TIME as data type for the columns fec and hor.

Comment: @Vmai That 2 indicates that 2 2233 items were sold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of SUM and IF:

```
SELECT 
    cod_f,
    SUM(IF(tdt = 'E', can, 0)) AS E,
    SUM(IF(tdt = 'S', can, 0)) AS S,
    SUM(IF(tdt = 'V', can, 0)) AS V,
    SUM(IF(tdt = 'D', can, 0)) AS D,
    SUM(IF(tdt = 'T', can, 0)) AS T
FROM venta
WHERE
    fdc = '07/08/2014' and local = 'xtorr'
GROUP BY cod_f;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cod, count(tdt), tdt
  FROM venta
 WHERE fdc = '07/08/2014'
  AND local = 'xtorr'
GROUP BY tdt, cod
ORDER BY cod, tdt;
```

This will then give you the count for each local and for each cod and tdt at that local on a specific date. My solution has a tdt column to distinguish which tdt the count for that cod corresponds to.

Comment: That won't account for the 2 in the sample result. Furthermore there are no E, S, V, D and T columns as required. You could learn from the answer of Peter van der Wal how this is done.

Comment: Thanks VMai. I'm not sure that the answer given by Peter is completely correct for what was being asked. I believe @user3063952 was wanting to get the number of transactions, not the number of units sold. If in a single transaction 2 units were sold (can = 2) it is still a single transaction is it not?

Comment: Please have a look at his answer to my comment about this in the comments to the question: *That 2 indicates that 2 2233 items were sold.* And he states in his question: *can is the number of pieces sold of that item for that sale*. I'm sure, Peter is right.

Comment: Yes, I see that. I guess his original question was a bit confusing to me. Peter's solution seems to fit his needs which is great and I learned from it as well. I'm just not sure why he hasn't marked it as the correct answer.

Comment: I hope he will accept the answer if he looks next at it. Peter wrote his answer less than tree minutes after @user3063952 answered my comment. Most times I look into StackOverflow I learn something new too.